# Translate smtlib2 model to COQ

Tags: coq, smt

All

I have a complicated model generated by tool in smtlib2 format. And I found it is hard to prove the SMT problem with SMT slover. So I want to translate this model to COQ and prove it in a different way.

Is there any COQ lib, plugin, tools can do this?
Thanks

Comment: You might have some luck with the SMTCoq tool (https://smtcoq.github.io/), though its main purpose is not what you are looking for. Out of curiosity, which tool is generating your smtlib model?

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim,  I uses [Yosys](https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys) to translate verilog RTL hardware to smtlib.